# Google Mock and Catch.hpp Integration

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I really like catch.hpp for testing (https://github.com/philsquared/Catch). I like its BDD style and its REQUIRE statements, its version of asserts. However, catch does not come with a mocking framework.

The project I'm working on has GMock and GTest but we've used catch for a few projects as well. I'd like to use GMock with catch.

I found 2 conflicts in the catch.hpp and gtests header files for the macros FAIL and SUCCEED. Since I'm not using the TDD style but instead the BDD style I commented them out, I checked that they weren't referenced anywhere else in catch.hpp.

**Problem**: Using `EXPECT_CALL()` doesn't return anything or have callbacks to know if the EXPECT passed. I want to do something like:

```
REQUIRE_NOTHROW(EXPECT_CALL(obj_a, an_a_method()).Times(::testing::AtLeast(1)));
```

**Question**: How can I get a callback if `EXPECT_CALL` fails (or a return value)

Comment: [trompeloeil](https://github.com/rollbear/trompeloeil) sounds interesting, and is designed to work with Catch. Personally, I'd try that before Google's behemoth.

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT:** Figured out how to integrate it and put an example in this github repo https://github.com/ecokeley/catch_gmock_integration

---

After hours of searching I went back to gmock and just read a bunch about it. Found this in ["Using Google Mock with Any Testing Framework"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#using-google-mock-with-any-testing-framework):

```
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true;
::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
```

This causes an exception to be thrown on a failure. They recommend ["Handling Test Events"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/48ee8e98abc950abd8541e15550b18f8f6cfb3a9/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#extending-google-test-by-handling-test-events) for more seamless integration.

```
class MinimalistPrinter : public ::testing::EmptyTestEventListener {
  // Called after a failed assertion or a SUCCEED() invocation.
  virtual void OnTestPartResult(const ::testing::TestPartResult& test_part_result) {
    printf("%s in %s:%d\n%s\n",
         test_part_result.failed() ? "*** Failure" : "Success",
         test_part_result.file_name(),
         test_part_result.line_number(),
         test_part_result.summary());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of the macros FAIL and SUCCEED in version 1.8.0 gmock added the following to gtest.h:

```
#if !GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_FAIL
  # define FAIL() GTEST_FAIL()
#endif

#if !GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_SUCCEED
  # define SUCCEED() GTEST_SUCCEED()
#endif
```

So by adding GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_FAIL and GTEST_DONT_DEFINE_SUCCEED to the preprocessor definitions you will avoid the conflict

Answer (score 2):

I created a small example how to integrate GMock with Catch2.

https://github.com/matepek/catch2-with-gmock

Hope it helps someone.

Disclaimer: It is not bulletproof. Feel free to contribute and improve.

Comment: Still using catch2 and gmock?

Comment: Not using much C++ right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is also gtestbdd in the cppbdd project which adds BDD support in a single header for gtest (rather than replacing it). It recently had an improvement to enable parameterized tests to work in a BDD style. There is a tutorial in the readme of:

https://github.com/Resurr3ction/cppbdd